# Can grass clippings be used for livestock feed?

Tags: balanced-ecosystems, agriculture

I was at a university agricultural research farm and I noticed that sheep had maintained grass height on a pasture to less than 1 inch.  I asked the person in charge if they used a lawn mower and he said "no, not needed".

I never throw away my grass clippings and always use them for compost.  But after seeing this self sustaining agricultural cycle, I am looking for ways to implement this.  The township ordinances will not allow me to rent livestock for "mowing the lawn" but I was wondering if I can take the grass clippings to farm for livestock feed.  Will livestock consume grass clippings?

Comment: They will, but do take care not to accidentally give them poisonous plants growing in grass, there's a bunch of those depending on where you live. And not all of those plants have the same effect on the different typs of animals (horses vs goats vs pigs vs ...)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I live on a farm and can say with certainty that cattle and sheep will absolutely eat grass clippings. All of our grass clippings from the around the house go to the animals, along with a significant amount of other garden waste. They not only eat grass but will strip leaves off tree trimmings, and eat fruit and vegetables that may no longer be suitable for human consumption for whatever reason.

Answer (score 4):

It will be more nutritious if, instead of "clippings", you use a scythe and rake up the cut grass. Grass clippings from a lawn mower oxidize very quickly since they are so finely chopped up.

Answer (score 1):

I used to dry grass clippings as hay, then bag and store until winter and feed to goats. They seemed to much prefer it to regular hay. I think it is more nutritious too.

Answer (score 1):

I can definitely say Yes. The grass clippings can be used for ruminant animals like sheep and goat after ensiling or drying of the grass clippings. That has been scientifically proved in our lab.

Comment: Welcome to Sustainable Living! Is there a research report or publication you could share?